# SQL Self Join with Count Function on same field different Where Clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, self-join

I have 2 queries against a single field on a single table that I want to join into a single query...

Query 1:

```
SELECT completed_by_id AS WHO
    , COUNT (activity_id) AS CALLS
FROM table1
WHERE activity_id = 'CALL'
    AND YEAR(completed_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(completed_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY completed_by_id
```

Returns:

```
WHO        *    CALLS
Joe Sales  *    5
Jane Sales *    8
```

Query 2:

```
SELECT completed_by_id AS WHO
    , COUNT (activity_id) AS VISITS
FROM table1
WHERE activity_id = 'VISIT'
    AND YEAR(completed_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(completed_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY completed_by_id
```

Returns:

```
WHO        *    VISITS
Joe Sales  *    2
Jane Sales *    3
```

Both of these work fine as is, but I'd like to have a single query that would return something like:

```
WHO          *   CALLS    *   VISITS  
Joe Sales    *     5      *    2
Jane Sales   *     8      *    3
```

I know I need a self join, but I'm not sure how to write the query.

Comment: Did you tried `union all` it works

Comment: Why not just add a conditional in the where, WHERE (activity_id = 'VISIT' OR activity_id = 'CALL')
They are identical other than that, a UNION seems like more code and overhead than necessary unless I'm missing something. Modify your select based on that.

Comment: Tag your question with the DBMS you are using so that people do not have to glean what you are using by the way your syntax looks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done pretty simply by using a CASE statement in your COUNT. COUNT just increments when it's non-null, so you can have a CASE return NULL when it's not what you're looking for, or you can use SUM instead and return 1/0.

```
SELECT
    completed_by_id AS WHO, 
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (activity_id='CALL' THEN 1 END)) AS CALLS,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN (activity_id='VISIT' THEN 1 END)) AS VISITS
FROM table1
WHERE 
    activity_id IN ('CALL','VISIT') -- This is optional, but it could help efficiency a bit
    AND YEAR(completed_date) = YEAR(GETDATE()) AND 
    MONTH(completed_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY completed_by_id
```

Comment: In your `WHERE` clause you are missing an AND after the first line

Comment: D'oh. Thanks. I was trying to figure out this whole syntax highlighting and kept messing with it too much.

Comment: No problem! Happens to everyone :)

Comment: Marking this one as answer since it's first, thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

```
    SELECT completed_by_id AS WHO
    , sum(case when activity_id= 'CALL' then 1 else 0 end) AS CALLS
    , sum(case when activity_id= 'visits' then 1 else 0 end) AS VISITS
FROM table1
WHERE activity_id in  ('CALL','visits')
    AND YEAR(completed_date) = YEAR(GETDATE())
    AND MONTH(completed_date) = MONTH(GETDATE())
GROUP BY completed_by_id
```

Comment: Above would be simplest